# .NET SOAP and complex data types

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, soap

Are there any issues in using List or any other complex data types with .NET SOAP web service? Is it best practice to use an array?

Answer (score 2):

Lists, arrays and other collections are converted into a soap-specific collection. So in the end, there is no difference in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter wether you use an array or a list, they are converted to SOAP as a repeating element.

FYI a client using WCF can chose to deserialize it as an array or a list.

Answer (score 1):

WebServices can serialize a lot, I have even seen them return `DataTable`s (not recommended).  However, I have found it cleaner to use [Data Transfer Objects (DTO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) when returning complex types.  These objects are created for your web service only and gives you more control over what your service returns.

If I need to return a list of items, I will use a plain old array vs an `IList`.  The generated WSDLs seem to be a lot cleaner this way.